# Mapping data from database into a JSON object Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, ajax, calendar, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I've installed Fullcalendar bundle (Symfony2) and all the events that I'm adding were showing correctly.  Now I add `eventClick` function in Fullcalendar.js (it works  with `open.window('page')` just for testing). Now I want to get all the information about this event (id,name,...etc) in an `alert()` or something else instead of `window.open()`.

How can I do that?

```
$(function () {
/* initialize the calendar
 -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
//Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate(),
    m = date.getMonth(),
    y = date.getFullYear();
$('#calendar-place').fullCalendar({
    monthNames: ["Janvier","Février","Mars","Avril","Mai","Juin","Julliet", "Aout", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Decembre" ],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Avr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Aou','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
    dayNames: [ 'Diamnche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Diu','Dill','Dim','Dix','Dij','Div','Dis'],

    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    buttonText: {
        today: 'today',
        month: 'month',
        week: 'week',
        day: 'day'
    },
    events:
    {
        url:Routing.generate('fullcalendar_loadevents', { month: moment().format('MM'), year: moment().format('YYYY') }),
        color: '#45b2ea',
        textColor:'white',

        error: function() {
            alert('Error receving events');
        }
    },
    viewRender: function (view, element) {
        var month = view.calendar.getDate().format('MM');
        var year = view.calendar.getDate().format('YYYY');
    },

    eventClick: function() {

       window.open('login')
    },





    eventDrop: function(event,delta,revertFunc) {
        var newStartData = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var newEndData = (event.end == null) ? newStartData : event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

        $.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate('fullcalendar_changedate'),
            data: { id: event.id, newStartData: newStartData,newEndData:newEndData  },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                console.log('ok');
            },
            error: function(e){
                revertFunc();
                alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
            }
        });

    },
    eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {

        var newData = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        $.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate('fullcalendar_resizedate'),
            data: { id: event.id, newDate: newData },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                console.log('ok');
            },
            error: function(e){
                revertFunc();
                alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
            }
        });

    },
    editable: true

});
});
```

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Briefly the event object always in eventCLick is undefined it show me in my console undefined property for title for expl although the eventdrop and event resize works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation of eventClick at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/ it shows you the parameters available to the callback, which includes an "event" object containing details of the clicked event.

So you can do something like this:

```
eventClick: function( event, jsEvent, view ) 
{ 
  alert(event.title);
}
```

You can find more properties of the event object here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ in case you want to use other information about the event.

Comment: The object event is undefined always in eventClick i followed the documentation evenDrop and resize works correctly just eventClick

Comment: Your code as it is currently doesn't declare the event object in your eventClick definition. You have to write it there, just like I've done in the answer. Once you do that, there's no reason it shouldn't work. Here's a working example using your calendar setup: https://jsfiddle.net/yog1jc45/1/ I have replaced the ajax source with some example events, because I can't call your ajax URL from the demo, but the principle is the same. If you click on an event, a popup appears showing the event's title, no problem.

Comment: I do what you already did now eventclick (event,jsEVent,view) and a simple alert show event.title it show me an error in alert (event.title) maybe as u say the ajax dosen't work which i can't get the object event

Comment: if you've got an event to click on (and so trigger the callback), then your data-loading ajax has worked at least to some extent. Maybe your event data doesn't provide a "title" field (it should do, because fullCalendar requires it)? You say "it show me an error in alert" - what error do you get?

Comment: I have a title field ( the title of event)

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle (or modify mine in such a way) to demonstrate this issue? I cannot reproduce that problem at all.

Comment: What a JSFIddle !! I think event undefined just just in eventclick the eventdrop and resoze works correctly

Comment: A JSFiddle, just like the one I linked to already - https://jsfiddle.net/yog1jc45/1/ - didn't you click on it??? It lets you edit code and markup all inside the browser environment. I made it to prove to you that the eventClick works properly, as long as you define it correctly.

Comment: I will wait with real interest. I genuinely don't think that what you're describing is possible, unless something else in your code is wrong which may be affecting it.