# Call FullCalendar by passing date from another website page - Odoo V10

Tags: fullcalendar, odoo-10

I have showed the full calendar into Odoo website home page by using the below source code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">

        <!-- Banner -->
        <template inherit_id="website.homepage" id="homepage_inherit">
            <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrap']" position="replace">
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
            <script  type="text/javascript" src='/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
            <script   type="text/javascript" src='/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
            <script   type="text/javascript" src='/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        /*
            jQuery document ready
        */

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            /*
                date store today date.
                d store today date.
                m store current month.
                y store current year.
            */
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            /*
                Initialize fullCalendar and store into variable.
                Why in variable?
                Because doing so we can use it inside other function.
                In order to modify its option later.
            */

            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
            {
                /*
                    header option will define our calendar header.
                    left define what will be at left position in calendar
                    center define what will be at center position in calendar
                    right define what will be at right position in calendar
                */
                header:
                {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                /*
                    defaultView option used to define which view to show by default,
                    for example we have used agendaWeek.
                */
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                /*
                    selectable:true will enable user to select datetime slot
                    selectHelper will add helpers for selectable.
                */
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                /*
                    when user select timeslot this option code will execute.
                    It has three arguments. Start,end and allDay.
                    Start means starting time of event.
                    End means ending time of event.
                    allDay means if events is for entire day or not.
                */
                select: function(start, end, allDay)
                {
                    /*
                        after selection user will be promted for enter title for event.
                    */
                    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                    /*
                        if title is enterd calendar will add title and event into fullCalendar.
                    */
                    if (title)
                    {
                        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                            {
                                title: title,
                                start: start,
                                end: end,
                                allDay: allDay
                            },
                            true // make the event "stick"
                        );
                    }
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                },
                /*
                    editable: true allow user to edit events.
                */
                editable: true,
                /*
                    events is the main option for calendar.
                    for demo we have added predefined events in json object.
                */
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                    },
                    {
                        id: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        id: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                        url: 'http://google.com/'
                    }
                ]
            });

        });
            </script>
            <div id='calendar'></div>
            </xpath>
        </template>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

Now i need to navigate from contactus page to home page with some date , calendar should load dayview with the date given,

```
 <template inherit_id="website.contactus" id="contactus_inherit">
            <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrap']" position="replace">
            <div class="text-center mt64" name="mail_button">
                        <a t-attf-href="#" onclick="alert('test');
                     var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();
            var n = new Date(y, m, d-3);
                                    window.href = '/homepage';
                                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', n)" class="btn btn-primary" id="o_contact_mail">Send us an email</a>
             </div>
           </xpath>
        </template>
```

Calling like above throws **"$..fullcalendar is not a function" error.**
how can i do this ? Please anyone provide me an idea to proceed this further !!!

Comment: Hi i'm working with this now can you help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444220/mapping-data-form-database-into-a-jason-object-fullcalendar

Comment: `window.href = '/homepage'; $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', n)"` This makes no sense. You are changing the URL in window.href. Any code you run here after that is pointless, it will get destroyed when the page refreshes a moment later. You could use something like `window.href="/homepage?date=2017.04.01` and pass the desired date on the querystring to the homepage. Then amend the homepage to read this value from the querystring. You can easily google how to do that. Be sure your date is URL-encoded and unambiguous.

Comment: P.S. The reason for the actual error message is presumably that the fullcalendar JS files are not referenced on your Contact Us page (and that's fine, because you don't need them there).